# Convert .class file  to .java file

Tags: java

Is this possible to convert a .class file (from .jar external library) to a .java file? I'm trying to figure out whether it is possible or not because the source of the external library is unavailable.

What are the steps I need to take to do this?

Comment: People's giving you good pointers to java decompilers. Just be aware that your library might be obfuscated, meaning a post compilation step took place where all package, class, field and method names where renamed to something unintelligible like A.b.c. Also, you'll loose the comments in the original source code no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

use a java decompiler like "Cavaj". It will open the class into a txt format, copy the code to a file and save as .java

Answer (score 1):

Use `jad`. Download it from [here](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/). It works fine with classes compiled up to SDK 1.4... 1.5, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The javap command takes class-names without the .class extension. Try

```
javap -c ClassName
```

javap will however not give you the implementations of the methods in java-syntax. It will at most give it to you in JVM bytecode format.
To actually decompile (i.e., do the reverse of javac) you will have to use proper decompiler. 
http://download.cnet.com/Cavaj-Java-Decompiler/3000-2213_4-10071619.html

or may be this be of some help [Java Decomilers](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0330.html)

Answer (score 0):

it is Possible to convert a class file to java file without using any tools . e.g Decompiler  or something else ?

Comment: Should have been a comment